# Instantiating a JdbcTemplate from a java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, spring, connection, datasource, jdbctemplate

I want to obtain a [`JdbcTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) in my Java code. I've already got a working [`java.sql.Connection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html). To create a new `JdbcTemplate` it would normally need an instance of the [`javax.sql.DataSource`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/sql/DataSource.html) interface.

Is it somehow possible to obtain a new `JdbcTemplate`from an existing `java.sql.Connection`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Technically, you can, using [`SingleConnectionDataSource`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/SingleConnectionDataSource.html)

`new JdbcTemplate(new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, false))`

However, this is not quite advisable, unless for unit-tests for example.

You'd better use a full-featured `DataSource` and wire things using spring.

Comment: Thanks for the work around, but nevertheless I've ended up implementing it in my application context.

Comment: +1 This makes perfect sense deep down in some Hibernate listener code of mine, where I already have the current open connection in my hand.

Answer (score 2):

No, JdcbTemplate is a Spring class; Connection is part of the JDK.  Connection knows nothing about JdbcTemplate.

The way to do it is to add a JdbcTemplate bean in your Spring app context; then inject it into the classes that need it declaratively.